# To find the file which displays the html content in Report builder

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting

> I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Report Builder .  I have designed
>   some reports and access it from the browser . The following image will
>   show the exact meaning :

[image: Report server in browser]

> I want to edit the above html page but i cannot find the file .
>
> This is the image in the ReportServer folder in program files .

[image]

Comment: URL's just [redirect to the Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261(v=sql.100)). By the way, you should have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on the type of questions you can ask on SO; you're typically expected to tell us what you've tried and what the specific problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are seeing is not a web page : it's the response from the SSRS web server. You cannot customize that view.